# How to output a certain blog on to a PAGE in shopify

Tags: blogs, shopify, liquid, dotliquid

I'm creating a [Shopify](https://www.shopify.com/?ref=microapps) store for a client who does not obviously know coding. He will need to update content on the website (and I have coded some pages with certain layouts (in the html part of the content) so when he types his content it often breaks our design)

As an alternative solution, I'm thinking of using the blog feature. 
I know [Shopify](https://www.shopify.com/?ref=microapps) lets us create a page with only a certain blog, but what it does is show up in the URL - as a ...blog/cocktails.

That is not good for the end user, because I merely want it to be a page that calls the blog articles from this blog. I'm unable to find a way to do it.

I tried replacing blog.content with blog['cocktail'].content and etc..
but it didn't do anything.

Alternatively are there any suggestions how you can design a page and let clients add their own content just by typing (for instances where its a list of recipes for example)?

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be best to create a custom page template same as blog page.

It will solve your all problems(i think) because first your url problem will be solved by it user has to just assign a template from backend.

Second one most important user can update its content from backend and it will not disturb your html.

If you still have problems just customise html and css.

I hope it will help you.

Comment: I have already created a template for this page. My question is how to make it render only a certain blog.????

Comment: For this you can use metafield or metafiled2 app. This app will workas a custom field, in this just give your post id or title and then fetch it.

Comment: But as i understand your requirment you can simply paste your blog content into page editor and then customise your template so that it works as your blog page with no/blog/ url